# How to take value from array into integer (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, element, json

Input :

```
$sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM matchTrip where userTripId = :tripId";

$stmt1 = $this->db->prepare($sql1);

$stmt1->bindParam(':tripId', $trip, PDO::PARAM_INT);                                              

$temp = $stmt1->fetchObject();

echo(json_encode($temp));
```

Output:

```
 How to take value from array : 

 of which json_encode looks like this: {"COUNT(*)":"7"}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `echo $array['COUNT(*)'];`

Comment: Why not iterate over the array and perform the check?

Comment: Why not print $temp instead of encode it..??

Comment: @Gautam3164 : when I print only $temp then it says print only this : Array

Comment: @Chiel92 : Actually I dont know how to iterate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just give the column an alias in the SQL itself?

```
$sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as myCount FROM matchTrip where userTripId = :tripId";
```

Makes the rest easier to work with.

Comment: Ok.But how to print myCount?

Comment: Got it.$temp->myCount.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `json_decode`? You can just put it between quotes and it should work; `$array["COUNT(*)"]`.

But you can also add "AS myCount" to your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

if to get rid of all the useless stuff from your code

```
$sql  = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM matchTrip where userTripId = ?";
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($table_of_user[$i]));
$count = $stmt->fetchColumn();

echo $count;
```

Answer (score 0):

So why not just fecth as array?

```
$temp = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $temp['COUNT(*)'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use like this:

```
$json = json_encode($temp);

echo $json->{'COUNT(*)'}; // 7
```